# First element of char array is getting initialized to null automatically.strings, scanf, printf

Tags: c, string, character, scanf

Input:9 notation

```
printf("Input N value\n");
scanf("%d",&N);
char X[N];
int i=0,N=0;
for (i=0;i<N-1;i++)
 {
scanf("%c",&X[i]);
}
X[N-1]='\0';


for (i=0;i<N-1;i++)
{
printf("%c",X[i]);
}
```

Expected output:notation
Output:notatio

Why is this so?

Comment: corrected my answer! (Don't know why i missed that one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the length with your first scanf call you leave a newline in your input buffer.

At the second scanf call the first character read is the newline and then the rest. Adding a space before the %c in your second scanf string parameter will consume any left newlines.

```
scanf(" %c",&X[i]);
```

You also don't null terminate your string, before printing it.

```
X[N-1] = '\0' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to substract 1 in your for loops, otherwise it will miss 1 character at the end!

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int charNumber, charCount;

    printf("Input N value\n>");
    scanf("%d", &charNumber);

    char text[charNumber+1];

    for (charCount = 0; charCount < charNumber; charCount++)
        scanf(" %c", &text[charCount]);

    text[charNumber] = '\0';

    for (charCount = 0; charCount <= charNumber; charCount++)
            printf("%c", text[charCount]);

    return 0;

}
```

You can also print the string with:

```
printf("%s", text);
```

Comment: You are doing the same mistakes as @Hari.

Comment: @2501 lol i looked at this older answer and saw it, updated it now.